# Update Symfony cache on PostPersist action

Tags: php, symfony, caching, doctrine

I'm trying to update the Symfony's cache on PostPersist action but it's not working.

What I do:

- Create en event subscriber, which one will update the cache. To do that, I get the pool with the key. I delete the cache then I create a new one but with fresh data.
- I call the event subscriber within the postPersist method.

On the main page, if the cache does not exists, it will be created. On the details page,
when I dump data in the callback function when I'm creating the cache, the findOneBy method returns result but without the new data. So the cache is not up to date. When I reload the page, I saw the new data. But on the page where the cache is called, it's the old data.

I didn't find this information but, the findOneBy method will fetch data from db or cache?

Thanks for helping me